# Comparing group means

Tags: r, data.table, mean

I have a dataset which looks as follows:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread(
  "A   B   C   fac   H   I   J   iso   year   matchcode
     0   1   1   NA   0   1   0   NLD   2009   NLD2009
     1   0   2   NA   1   0   1   NLD   2009   NLD2009
     0   0   3   B    1   0   0   AUS   2011   AUS2011
     1   0   4   B    0   1   0   AUS   2011   AUS2011
     0   1   7   NA   0   0   0   NLD   2008   NLD2008
     1   0   1   A    0   1   0   NLD   2008   NLD2008
     0   0   3   B    1   0   0   AUS   2012   AUS2012
     1   0   4   B    0   1   0   AUS   2012   AUS2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

For each country I would like to check, if the mean value of `C` changes over time. So I did:

```
setDT(df)[, c("MeanValue_C", "Residual_C") := {m= mean(C, na.rm=TRUE);list(m, C-m)}, by=list(iso, year)]
```

This essentially gives me the information I want. However not in any useful format. I tried to do `table(df$MeanValue_C, df$matchcode)`, but that created a big mess, because the actual dataset has about 100 countries with 2 or more years.

What would be the easiest way to compare the group means for each country, without creating an additional datatable?

Ideally something like:

```
df2 <- fread(
  "C   iso   year   matchcode
     1.5   NLD   2009   NLD2009
     3.5   AUS   2011   AUS2011
     4     NLD   2008   NLD2008
     3.5   AUS   2012   AUS2012",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Unclear what you're after exactly. You have the year-by-year means; you want to visualize them? Do some statistical testing? Summarize?

Comment: I have added some example output. I guess for the moment I would simply like to summarise them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start. You can run `summary` on the yearly averages for each country to get some basic sample moments for each country. `summary` returns a vector of the 5-number summary + mean; `as.list` converts this so each element will be a column. `keyby` sorts the grouping (i.e. it runs `setkey` after performing the operation):

```
df[ , .(c_mean = mean(C, na.rm = TRUE)), keyby = .(iso, year, matchcode)
    ][ , as.list(summary(c_mean)), keyby = .(iso, matchcode)]
#    iso matchcode Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
# 1: AUS   AUS2011  3.5     3.5    3.5  3.5     3.5  3.5
# 2: AUS   AUS2012  3.5     3.5    3.5  3.5     3.5  3.5
# 3: NLD   NLD2008  4.0     4.0    4.0  4.0     4.0  4.0
# 4: NLD   NLD2009  1.5     1.5    1.5  1.5     1.5  1.5
```

Unfortunately, the output type of `summary` is not guaranteed to be length-5 like it is here. In particular, for numeric, it will be length-6 if there are any `NA_real_` values in the input. Since you already ran `na.rm = TRUE`, this is only possible if there's a `iso`-`matchcode` combination with no non-`NA` values (to confirm this, run `summary(mean(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE))`). To proceed, you can for example drop such values up front:

```
df[ , keyby = .(iso, year, matchcode),
   if (!all(is.na(C)) .(c_mean = mean(C, na.rm = TRUE)), 
    ][ , as.list(summary(c_mean)), keyby = .(iso, matchcode)]
```

Or drop them intermediately:

```
df[ , .(c_mean = mean(C, na.rm = TRUE)), keyby = .(iso, year, matchcode)
    ][!is.na(c_mean), as.list(summary(c_mean)), keyby = .(iso, matchcode)]
```

Or, if you don't want to lose that information (that some combinations are missing), you can force the output to be more consistent:

```
df[ , .(c_mean = mean(C, na.rm = TRUE)), keyby = .(iso, year, matchcode)
    ][ , {
      s = summary(c_mean)
      if (length(s) == 5L) s = c(s, `NA's` = 0L)
      as.list(s)
    }, keyby = .(iso, matchcode)]
```

(You can examine the code of `summary.default` by running `print(summary.default)` to assure yourself that this should work)

Comment: That's pretty neat. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For my actual dataset, the solution gives the error: `Error in [.data.table(df[, .(c_mean = mean(C, na.rm = TRUE)),  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group` Do you have any idea what could be the issue? Could it be that this happens when in some country-year `C` is not available at all?

Comment: @Tom try with `[!is.na(c_mean)]` as the second `i` clause. `summary(mean(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE))` gives 6 columns...

Comment: I just verified that the problem indeed is that `C` is NA for some country-years (and that it works for another variable without NA's). I do however not completely understand what you propose to do in your comment. Would it be possible to show me exactly what you mean with an edit?

Comment: I figured out what you meant, it works now! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just to be clear: you have been a super big help and I already have what I wanted. But for the sake of the question here on stackoverflow: I just realised that the summary statistics are all the same (min, max, mean, are all the same), it would however be quite interesting to actually have that information from the observational level. How would that work (I could also just post it as a separate question I guess)?

Also as a last note: I also tried your edit, and that did not work for my dataset (makes me get the same error as before).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't say explicitly that the solution needs to be `data.table`, but a `tidyverse` solution to get the stated output is:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(iso, year, matchcode) %>% 
  summarise(C = mean(C)) %>% 
  select(C, iso, year, matchcode) 

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   iso, year [4]
      C iso    year matchcode
  <dbl> <chr> <int> <chr>    
1   3.5 AUS    2011 AUS2011  
2   3.5 AUS    2012 AUS2012  
3   4   NLD    2008 NLD2008  
4   1.5 NLD    2009 NLD2009
```